Rhinoceros 8, Grasshopper and sys.path in Python IDE
I work with Rhino 3d and Grasshopper to support an engineer with some programming work in Python. The Python runtime was automatically installed to C:\Users\Patrick Bucher\.rhinocode\py39-rh8. The scripts work fine when executed in the integrated Python editor. However, we'd like to use an external IDE (Visual Studio Code, PyCharm) to program and to write some tests using PyTest.
For this purpose, I created a Virtual Environment based on the existing one:
'C:\Users\Patrick Bucher\.rhinocode\py39-rh8\python.exe' -m venv env --system-site-packages

Note the --system-site-packages flag to prefix the path with the site packages.
However, I cannot run the following script from my virtual environment (demo.py):
import Rhino
dir(Rhino)

Result:
> python .\demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Patrick Bucher\solartables-constructable\demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Rhino
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Rhino

So I ran the following script in Grasshopper to get the proper path:
import sys
print(sys.path)

Which outputs:
['C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-envs\\default-kG+mgfz0', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\AppData\\Roaming\\McNeel\\Rhinoceros\\8.0\\scripts', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-rhinoghpython', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-rhinopython', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-interop', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Rhino 8\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.NETCore.App\\7.0.0\\']

So I compared this to my environment that I run from the IDE (syspathdiff.py):
import sys
rhino = set(['C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-envs\\default-kG+mgfz0', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\AppData\\Roaming\\McNeel\\Rhinoceros\\8.0\\scripts', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-rhinoghpython', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-rhinopython', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-interop', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Rhino 8\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.NETCore.App\\7.0.0\\'])
actual = set(sys.path)
missing = rhino - actual
print(missing)

Which outputs the following differences:
{'C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.NETCore.App\\7.0.0\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Rhino 8\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-rhinoghpython', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\AppData\\Roaming\\McNeel\\Rhinoceros\\8.0\\scripts', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-interop', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-envs\\default-kG+mgfz0', 'C:\\Users\\Patrick Bucher\\.rhinocode\\py39-rh8\\site-rhinopython'}

Here are my questions:

How do I configure my (virtual) environment so that the Rhino module can be imported upon running PyTest test cases or any other scripts involving Rhino?
Which additional path shall I include in order to have access to the Rhino module in my Python code?

Thanks!
EDIT: There is a RhinoCommon.dll for the CLR, which can be imported using the pythonnet package (pip install pythonnet):
try:
    import Rhino.Geometry as rg
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import clr
    rhino = clr.AddReference(r"C:\Program Files\Rhino 8\System\netcore\RhinoCommon.dll")
    print(rhino)

Output:
RhinoCommon, Version=8.6.24101.5001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=552281e97c755530

I don't know how to use the resulting library in Python. Any hints on this?

From my searches, it seems like Rhino is not a regular Python module ... Maybe it's only available when you are writing scripts to interact with the CAD software? And in that sense, it would not be alike other Python libraries or modules that are open source/available online...

@Guillius It looks like Rhino is a DLL: import Rhino; print(Rhino.__file__) gives C:\Program Files\Rhino 8\System\netcore\RhinoCommon.dll.  Any ideas on how to use that via a Python venv?

The file command says: PE32 executable (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows, 3 sections

Hi, I'm no expert in .dll, Microsoft Visual Studio or C#... But I think you got a C# library on your hands now (RhinoCommon API documentation can be found online)... Maybe (big maybe!) you can look into whether you can call functions of the dll from Python or something like that...
